Why does `os.Chir` not switching directory when used inside a Goroutine?
I'm creating simple examples to test out my understanding of Go concurrency model, I come across this interesting issue and track it down to os.Chdir causing the issue:
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    basePath := "/User/MyUser/Desktop"
    repos := []string{
        basePath + "/golang/tester",
        basePath + "/golang/another_tester",
        basePath + "/golang/does_not_exist",
    }

    resultCh := make(chan string)

    for _, v := range repos {
        go func(path string) {
            result := printWorkingDirectory(path)
            resultCh <- result
        }(v)
    }

    for i := 0; i < len(repos); i++ {
        fmt.Println(<-resultCh)
    }
}

func printWorkingDirectory(dir string) string {
    err := os.Chdir(dir)
    if err != nil {
        return "Error changing directory"
    }

    commands := "pwd"
    var output bytes.Buffer

    cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c", commands)
    cmd.Stdout = &output

    if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
        return "Error getting working directory"
    }

    return strings.TrimSuffix(output.String(), "\n")
}

When I run the example above, I keep getting:
Error changing directory
Error changing directory
Error changing directory

even though two of the directories are valid and exist.
However, if I modify printWorkingDirectory to get rid of os.Chdir and instead change directory like this instead:
func printWorkingDirectory(dir string) string {
    commands := fmt.Sprintf("cd %s && pwd", dir)
    var output bytes.Buffer

    cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c", commands)
    cmd.Stdout = &output

    if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
        return "Error getting working directory"
    }

    return strings.TrimSuffix(output.String(), "\n")
}

Then it produces the desired result:
/User/MyUser/Desktop/golang/tester
/User/MyUser/Desktop/golang/another_tester
Error getting working directory

Does anybody know why os.Chdir produces this behavior? Also, is using the second approach guaranteed to produce the correct result every time?

What version of go are you using? A more recent version will probably work as exected. This is relared to how loop variables are treated. You may be only testing the laxt item in the slice

I'm using version 1.21 @BurakSerdar

I dont think it related to loop related behaviour. OP is passing the loop variable v to the func as argument so it should be copied. @BurakSerdar

@JSstarter Can you print err returned by os.Chdir before returning.

You are correct, @Ch3steR, it cannot be related to loopvar.

@Ch3steR here's what I get, the result is slightly different from the first one I posted, which is still not correct:
chdir /User/MyUser/Desktop/golang/does_not_exist: no such file or directory
Error changing directory
/User/MyUser/Desktop/golang/tester
/User/MyUser/Desktop/golang/tester

Current directory is a concept of the running process. When you change directories in multiple goroutines, you are creating a race condition where the last goroutine to execute os.Chdir will win. You create three goroutines, all of which change directories. By the time you execute the shell, it appears that all three goroutines finish their os.Chdir and the last one wins. So all executions of the shell produce the same output.
The second code segment will always produce the correct result, because chdir will run for each child process, and they will all chane into their respective directories.
